# GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" in quickblox login in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am using `QuickBlox SDK` in my iOS app, when I am trying to login in `QuickBlox` getting below error.

> [ChatService] Did disconnect with error: Error
>   Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760381/quickblox-gcdasyncsocketerrordomain-error

Comment: Do you have any additional logs or special case for this issue?

Comment: Do you have solution for this issue ?